# Lightning : How to add a button that executes a method at server side?

Tags: custom-button, lightning, action, global-actions

I am consuming a web service that gets me leads from another plateform. All this is done in a method in the apex class.

In Salesforce Classic, I am able to create a custom button where I can call that method via javascript.

What is the solution to add the button  that executes the server side method in Lightning?

Preferably, the button is wished at the position highlighted below :

[image: The main view of my Leads tab]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You will create a Custom Button of type "Visualforce" rather than Javascript .

Your visualforce will have an action method calling the apex server Side call .

The other way would be to create a Publisher Action and the Publisher action will link to a visualforce and a controller method calling apex .

Note to add "StandardController=Lead" and the button should appear in the lightning UI